# Mongodb updateMany command in node script doesn't require exec() like others

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have access to multiple dbs in my code, for some we use `"mongoose": "4.11.7"`, but for the one in question, let's call it dbOne, we use `"mongoose": "4.6.1"`. I recently needed to write a node script to update a collection on dbOne, and to do so, I wrote a command like the following:

#### example 1

```
try {
     await data.dbOne.CollectionOne.update({}, {
        $unset: {
            "attributeOne": "",
        }}, {multi: true}).exec();
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

This worked fine, so I moved on. However, I now have to update another collection in the same db, let's call it `CollectionTwo` and for some reason a similar command as above DOES NOT WORK! I.e.

#### example 2

```
try {
    await data.dbOne.CollectionTwo.update({}, {
        $unset: {
            "attributeOne": "",
        }}, {multi: true}).exec();
 } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Instead, what is working is the following:

#### example 3

```
try {
    let results = await data.dbOne.CollectionTwo.collection.updateMany({attributeOne: {$exists: true}}, {$set: {attributeOne: ""}});
    console.log("Unset attributeOne");
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Notice how I had to do the following things in the 3rd example for it work:

- use `updateMany` instead of `update`
- append the `collection` keyword
- remove the `exec()` (I was getting an error saying that `exec()` was not a function)

Now, I have looked around, but I am not sure if this issue is related to the `moogoose` version difference, `mongodb`, somehow something about the schema object, or what, so I am not sure where to look for an explanation. Any hints, suggestions, or answers would be greatly appreciated, I really want to understand what is happening here.